# Dynamically path: Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path

Tags: django, django-urls

I have tons of generic pattern like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('json/ay/<int:pk>', AyView.as_view(), name='json_ay'),
    path('json/by/<int:pk>', ByView.as_view(), name='json_by'),
    ...
]
```

(Of course, the classes are not simply `Ay` or `By` this is for the sake of clarity), I'm trying to convert them into a generic function like this:

```
first_cap_re = re.compile('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)')
all_cap_re = re.compile('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])')
def convert(name):
    s1 = first_cap_re.sub(r'\1_\2', name)
    return all_cap_re.sub(r'\1_\2', s1).lower()


def json_view(view_class):
    view_name = '_'.join(convert(view_class.__name__).split('_')[:-1])
    return path(f'json/{view_name}/<int:pk>', view_class.as_view(),
                name=f'json_{view_name}'),
```

and then call it like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    json_view(AyView),
    json_view(ByView),
    ...
]
```

I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern (<URLPattern 'json/ay/<int:pk>' [name='json_ay']>,) 
    is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.
    HINT: Try using path() instead of a tuple.
```

I dont know why, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an extra comma at the end of your return statement that is causing it to return a tuple. Remove the comma.

```
return path(f'json/{view_name}/<int:pk>', view_class.as_view(),
            name=f'json_{view_name}')
                                   # ^
```

Comment: Incredible how sometimes external views are useful. I should stop work alone. Sometimes "Alone you go faster, in team you go further" is not true!